# Having trouble testing RadioGroup with RoboGuice + Robolectric

Tags: android, tdd, radio-group, roboguice, robolectric

I have looked at this a bunch of different ways and with what little hair I have left, I thought I would put it out there in the hope someone has already tried this.

I am trying to write a Robolectric test of my Roboguice enabled Activity. Specifically, I am trying to write test that ensure the behavior of a RadioGroup.

The problem is that when running the test, the RadioGroup does not act like a RadioGroup and enforce the only-one-RadioButton-checked-at-a-time behaviour. I can see by both Asserting and with the debugger that I can check all three of the buttons in the group at once.

The RadioGroup is very straightforward:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/whenSelection"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/whenToday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/today" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/whenYesterday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/yesterday" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/whenOther"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/earlier" />

</RadioGroup>
```

I should point on then what I run the app, the behaviour is what I expect (that if I click on any of the radio buttons only that one remains checked, and the other two are unchecked). So, in theory, this test should pass:

```
    -- snip--
    Assert.assertTrue(whenToday.isChecked());
    Assert.assertFalse(whenYesterday.isChecked());
    Assert.assertFalse(whenOther.isChecked());

    whenYesterday.performClick();

    Assert.assertTrue(whenYesterday.isChecked());
    Assert.assertFalse(whenToday.isChecked());
    -- snip --
```

But, what happens is that the last assertion fails, and the debugger confirms that the first button whenToday has remained checked.

Here is the full test class:

```
@RunWith(InjectedTestRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Inject ActivityLogEdit activity;

    RadioButton whenToday;
    RadioButton whenYesterday;
    RadioButton whenOther;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    activity.setIntent(new Intent());
    activity.onCreate(null);

    whenSelection = (RadioGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.whenSelection);
    whenToday = (RadioButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.whenToday);
    whenYesterday = (RadioButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.whenYesterday);
    whenOther = (RadioButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.whenOther);       
}

@Test
public void checkDateSelectionInitialState() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertTrue(whenToday.isChecked());
    Assert.assertFalse(whenYesterday.isChecked());
    Assert.assertFalse(whenOther.isChecked());
    Assert.assertEquals(View.GONE, logDatePicker.getVisibility());

    whenYesterday.performClick();

    Assert.assertTrue(whenYesterday.isChecked());
    Assert.assertFalse(whenToday.isChecked());
  }
}
```

I have tried this every different way I can think of. I have the feeling I am doing something stupid or missing some basic concept. Please help!

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer to a post on the Robolectric Group from one of the guys who develops it:

> The functionality you're talking about (checking a radio button will
>   uncheck all other radio buttons in the group) is not yet implemented
>   in Robolectric.  Feel free to file a feature request:
>   https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/issues/
>   If I remember correctly, try changing your tests to use
>   getCheckedRadioButtonId() on  the RadioGroup instead of isChecked() on
>   the RadioButtons--I believe that is implemented.

Note that I also tried `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` and it is also unimplemented (always returns -1).

Andrew